# Avoiding overlapping charts on a map with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, overlapping-features, mapping, leaflet-plugins

I'm currently developing an online GIS with Leaflet and need to plot bar charts on a map. I'm using leaflet.minichart (https://rte-antares-rpackage.github.io/leaflet.minichart/) for the charts. 
My problem is that some of the bar charts are overlapping - usually due the proximity of the centroids of my polygons. You can see a good example in the attached printscreen on the darkest polygon. 
I would like to avoid such overlaps and at this stage I'm fairly agnostic to the type of solution - I just want to ensure a nice rendering along with user-friendliness. Here below my code:

```
function add_poly_charts(features){
            var feature; // contains the polygon centroid and name, while polygon_charts is an array containing the data for each polygon

            // size simply changing with the number of charts, this si what we woudl like to automate to avoid collisions
            var size=80;
            if(n_poly_charts>5){
                size=30;
            }

            for (var i=0; i< features.features.length; i++){
                feature=features.features[i];
                var chart=L.minichart([feature.properties.centroid_y,feature.properties.centroid_x],
                                      {data: polygon_charts[feature.properties.adm],type:"bar",height:size,width:size, labels: names_list,
                                      colors:chart_colors});

                poly_charts.push(chart);
                mymap.addLayer(chart);
            }

        }
```

[image: Map developed with Leaflet and overlapping charts developed with leaflet.minichart]

Comment: I'm a newbie in GIS, I'm creating WebGIS like you. so, please may you give me your source code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Problem you are having is usually solved by method called *marker clustering*. This means that if several markers/icons are so close together that they overlap, they are replaced by symbolic *cluster* icon, which usually displays also number of included markers. Upon clicking on this cluster icon, all contained icons are shown in a circle around cluster icon, connected to it with lines (spiderfiering).

In your case you are using `Leaflet.minichart` plugin which does not offer this functionality. It's objects (charts) are extensions of Leaflet `L.CircleMarker` object, which is special case of vector layer. This means that also none of the marker clustering solutions (like Leaflet.markercluster plugin) can be used in combination with `Leaflet.minichart` plugin.

So, in short, you are out of luck here for out of the box solution. Programing custom solution? A lot of work, you can have a look at one of the clustering plugins code.

Comment: Thank you @TomazicM - are you aware of another Leaflet plugin enabling marker clustering with markers like charts?

Comment: There is no such plugin, but you can create your own solution using/combining the following elements: `Leaflet.markercluster` plugin (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) for marker clustering, standard `L.marker` markers with `L.divIcon` icons to contain charts and `Chart.js` library (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) to create charts. If you get stuck in trying to implement this, ask a new question.